# Get only (date) from (date + time) fromat in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, core-data

I am using core data and I store a value in date and time format. But I want to get only (date) format while I'm getting in the date and time format.

Comment: By using NSDateFormatter you can get only date / time .

Comment: How is the value stored in Core Data? As String or as Date attribute? If it is stored as String, what is the exact format? Can you given an example?

Comment: @Thukaram -- ???  NSDateFormatter will give you only date, only time, only the month --- whatever you ask for.

Comment: **WHAT FORMAT IS THE DATE???**  Is is an NSDate, an NSString, an integer milliseconds since 1970 or what?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to get the record for a specified date regardless the time. I have a Data attribute in Core Data which has dates stored like 2014-1-14 13:30:00. I don't care about the time for now, I only want the records with the same date as 2014-1-14

Comment: Guys, He Has NSDate format in Database like `2014-1-14 13:30:00`. Now what he wants is, Fetch all the records but the date field should have Date format like `2014-1-14` not `2014-1-14 13:30:00`. Please stop putting the predicate for fetching data with respect to date.He wants all data with different date format in it. That's it.

Comment: @iEngineer: An `NSDate` object is an absolute point in time and does not have a format (like "2014-1-14 13:30:00"). The same is true for a Core Data "Date" attribute.

Answer (score 2):

`NSDate` is an absolute point in time and Core Data stores a date as the number of seconds
since the "reference date" Jan 1, 2001. So strictly speaking, there is no such thing as a
"date without a time".

If you want to *display* year, month, day … of a date then you have to use a NSDateFormatter
or NSDateComponents - as the others already said - to convert the date into a human readable
format.

But from your comments I assume that you want to *fetch* all objects of a specified
day. In that case, you have to compute the *start and end date* of the given day first:

```
NSDate *yourDate = ...;
NSDate *startOfDay, *endOfDay;
NSTimeInterval lengthOfDay;
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfDay interval:&lengthOfDay forDate:yourDate];
endOfDay = [startOfDay dateByAddingTimeInterval:lengthOfDay];
```

Alternatively, if the day is given as year, month, day:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comps.year = 2014;
comps.month = 1;
comps.day = 14;
NSDate *startOfDay = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
comps.day += 1;
NSDate *endOfDay = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
```

And then use a predicate that finds all records between start and end of the day:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ AND date < %@",
             startOfDay, endOfDay];
```

This will fetch all objects that have a "date" on the same day as the given `yourDate`.

Comment: Understand the question first. He do not want to implement any filter. He wants all data without any filtration but changed date format of NSDate field (attribute).

Comment: @iEngineer: I *have* tried to understand the question including the following comments. In particular from the comment *"What I'm trying to do is to get the record for a specified date regardless the time. ... I only want the records with the same date as 2014-1-14"* I have concluded that that OP wants to fetch records for a particular date.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the data from coredata, if you are storing it as `NSDate` format or `NSString` format the process will be almost similar different.

If it is `NSDate`:

Create a `NSDateFormatter` to give you only date say in (dd-mm-yyyy) format, you will get a `NSString` object.

If it is `NSString`:

Then you need to first convert the string date into `NSDate` and do the above thing.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"date-format"]; //here you need to change the format as per your string
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: sir i am actually getting data from data base and i want this data only date formate because i want compare this with only date not for time.

Comment: As you want to compare only date, then you can not do it with NSDate, you need to use NSString and compare two strings.

Comment: Or you can strip the time off of both dates with `NSDateComponents` and compare.

Comment: but any method you knows which convert DB date and time only date formate